# What does "werden X nach Y unterschieden" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

The full sentence is:

> In vielen Sprachen **werden** die Nomen **nach** dem Genus **unterschieden**.

I've checked the meaning of every single word, but I'm still not sure what the sentence means. Especially, the "nach ... unterschieden" part isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In vielen Sprachen werden die Nomen nach dem Genus unterschieden.

Here, **nach** functions like the English *according to/by*. The werden + verb structure is the passive, rendering:

> In many languages, nouns are differentiated according to/by gender.

Another similar example with perhaps a less confusing verb:

> Die Artikel werden nach Preis aufsteigend sortiert.
>   *Items are sorted by ascending price.*